# Swift: check if date is the same date as any day in array of dates?

Tags: swift

I have an array of date objects - posts. And I am looping through a month. For each day, I want to check if some date in the array is on the same day. So far I have this:

```
var date = month?.startOfMonth()
var end = month?.endOfMonth()
while date! <= end! {
   if posts.reduce(false,{Calendar.current.isDate(date, inSameDayAsDate: post.timeStamp)}) == true {
      ....
   }
   date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date!)

}
```

I believe that this starts with false and for each day in posts it checks whether its in the same day and if it is it turns the result into true. However I think it also changes it back to false the next time it encounters a false value...

What I want is something that returns true if any of the dates in posts is the same as some day rather than the last one. How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to know if any date in the `posts` array is any day of `month`? Is that correct?

Comment: @rmaddy For a month, I need to know which dates exist in the posts array (same day, not necessarily same time). So perhaps for the 2nd and 15th, those dates are contained in the posts array. I am doing this by looping through day by day and verifying whether or not each day is contained in the array. Perhaps there are other ways to achieve it though

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just filter the array for all the elements which are within the specified month? Why do you need to know the date value?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am basically building a stack view - for every day - I create a rectangle which is blue if there is a post that day and clear if not. Thus I probably do need to know the day. However filtering the array for elements which are in the specified month seems interesting. Can you show how to do that? Perhaps I could specify the location of just those days and then fill the rest of the stackArray with clear values using insertItem atIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is mostly OK though I would replace `reduce` with `contains`.

```
if let start = month?.startOfMonth(), let end = month?.endOfMonth() {
    var date = start
    var found = false
    while !found && date <= end {
        if posts.contains { Calendar.current.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: $0.timeStamp) } {
            found = true
        }
        date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)
    }

    if found {
        // We have a match
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `posts.contains { ... }` instead of `posts.first { ... } != nil` ?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, that's probably a better choice than `first(where:)`. Same efficiency in this case but `contains` is more obvious.

Comment: xcode suggested this: if posts.contains(where: { Calendar.current.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: $0.timeStamp) }) {
                        found = true
                    }. Note the where clause and the inSameDayAs (removing the Date part). Also it wanted a ! after the date reassignment

Comment: Either syntax is fine. I used the "trailing closure" syntax. The `inSameDayAsDate` was a copy and paste typo from your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated]** As rightly mentioned already, you might be more interested in having a `Set` of days that have at least one post, something like:

```
let dayComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day, .month, .year, .era]
let calendar = Calendar.current

let daysWithPosts = Set(posts.map { post in
        calendar.dateComponents(dayComponents, from: post.date)
    })
```

Then for each `date` you can check if it's in that set (context unchanged, mind the force unwraps):

```
while date! <= end! {
    let currentDayComponents = calendar.dateComponents(dayComponents, from: date)
    let postsFound = daysWithPosts.contains(currentDayComponents)
    // <use postsFound as needed>
    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date!)
}
```

---

*Original answer, adapted for multiple dates:*

This should tell if there are posts on a given date's day:

```
func areTherePosts(in posts: [Post], fromSameDayAs date: Date) -> Bool {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dayComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day, .month, .year, .era]
    let specificDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(dayComponents, from: date)

    return posts.contains { post in
        calendar.dateComponents(dayComponents, from: post.date) == specificDateComponents
    }
}
```

Usage in your context (again, unchanged):

```
while date! <= end! {
    let postsFound = areTherePosts(in: posts, fromSameDayAs: date!)
    // <use postsFound as needed>
    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date!)
}
```

Comment: So with this, I would still loop over every day in the month - checking this each time correct? It just wouldn't have to loop through posts every time?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I have misinterpreted the question first. Indeed, since you want to know for _each_ day if there was a post, you have to check each day anyway. Will edit the answer to make it more relevant to the question.

Comment: However, assuming the use case you've posted later, I agree a more efficient approach would be to use the days in a `Set` or `Dictionary`. I.e. you can go through all posts once and memorise all days they were posted on (I'd still identify days by `DateComponents`). Then you can instantly say whether a post was made on a specific day — or, in case of a dictionary, what exact posts those were.

Answer (score 1):

> I am basically building a stack view - for every day - I create a rectangle which is blue if there is a post that day and clear if not. Thus I probably do need to know the day. However filtering the array for elements which are in the specified month seems interesting. Can you show how to do that? Perhaps I could specify the location of just those days and then fill the rest of the stackArray with clear values using insertItem atIndex

Basically, I might start with two functions, one to filter the dates by month and one to filter by day.  The reason I would so this, in your case, is you for each day, you don't want to refilter all the available dates for the month (but that's just me)

```
func dates(_ dates: [Date], withinMonth month: Int) -> [Date] {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.month]
    let filtered = dates.filter { (date) -> Bool in
        calendar.dateComponents(components, from: date).month == month
    }
    return filtered
}

func dates(_ dates: [Date], forDay day: Int) -> [Date] {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.day]
    let filtered = dates.filter { (date) -> Bool in
        calendar.dateComponents(components, from: date).day == day
    }
    return filtered
}
```

You could, use a `contains` approach, matching both the month and day, but again, there is an overhead to consider.  In the above example, you could simply check to see if the day is contained in the resulting filtered dates by month, which might be closer to you desired result

*nb* This is not as efficient as something like `first` or `contains` as this will iterate the entire array finding every matching element, but, it has the nice side effect of providing you with more information.  For example, you could sort the resulting filters and simply iterate from the start of the month to the end, popping off each match day as it occurs, as an idea

## Thinking out loud...

Another approach might be to filter the available date's by the month, as above, but then to map the result to a `Set` of days (ie `Int`), this would allow you to either iterate over each day of the month and use `contains(day)` to perform a simple check to see if the day is contained or not.

Equally, you could map the view's to each day and iterate of the `Set`, changing the state of each view.

This all depends on more context then is available, but needless to say, there are any number of ways you might approach this problem